# how to color javabeans getter and setter methods in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, colors

I work on a Java project that requires me to access all private object fields through getter and setter methods from the same class. Because of this, I am missing the coloring Eclipse so nicely does on all object data fields, by default blue. Is there a way make Eclipse color the getters and setters when they are used instead of the fields directly? Here is an example of what I need:

```
class MyClass {
    private int number;
    private int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        int a = getNumber();
    }
}
```

I need the call getNumber() in the method doSomething() colored blue. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

All the colors you can set are configured in `Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring`. There does not appear to be anything to color getters and setters differently.

Comment: Sure, right out of the box Eclipse cannot do it. There ought to be a way to program this, though.

Comment: To program this the Eclipse JDT syntax coloring would need to be extensible, to best of my knowledge there is no way to extend this other than hacking the JDT source.

Comment: @Bolot I also look forward for a way to color private methods differently than public ones. I am using unnecessary method name modifications like private _someMethodName() that I think is awful, but helps me on making things more clear.. so if you find anything, share! :D